# cakephp insert on different table

Tags: php, database, forms, cakephp

I'm trying to insert the data of the following form in a table of database that is not the "default" one. However, i don't know how to do it, i'm still adapting to cakephp. I guess the form is done correctly and the names of the specific table on database are the ones in the inputs. But i'm not saying anywhere which table he should insert right? Is that not necessary? Or in case it's needed, what am i missing to specify the table i want?

```
    <?php   echo $this->Form->create('Ficha', array('action' => 'index')); ?>
//echo $this->Form->input('id_fichas', array('label' => 'Id Ficha:'));
echo $this->Form->input('class_subst', array('label' => 'Class mistura:'));
echo $this->Form->input('simbolos_perigo', array('label' => 'Símbolos:'));
echo $this->Form->input('frases_r', array('label' => 'Frases:'));
echo $this->Form->end('Finalizar Ficha'); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

By convention table objects will use a table that matches the lower cased and underscored version of the class name. In your case 'Ficha' will be mapped to 'fichas' table. If you want a different table you need to define it, based on the CakePHP version:

### CakePHP 3.x

You can specify the table using the *setTable()* method:

```
class Example extends Table {

    public function initialize(array $config) {
        $this->setTable('my_table');

        // Prior to 3.4.0 use 'table' method
        // $this->table('my_table');
    }
}
```

Link to [3.x docs](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/table-objects.html)

### CakePHP 2.x

The attribute *$useTable* in your Model will do the magic:

```
<?php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');

class Example extends AppModel {
   public $useTable = 'exmp'; // This model uses a database table 'exmp'
}
```

Link to [2.x docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html)

Comment: Hello Carlos,
but i need to use a different table just in some occasions. In the ones you mention (add, edit), i'm using a default table, but i need to access a second one in the middle of the process, that's what i am asking. Thank you!

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding, but i guess that what i'm looking for is this, since the tables i want to use will be linked:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html